# How can I change Angular Material mat-autocomplete text color to white after an option is chosen?

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material

I am not looking to change the placeholder color as I've already got that done, but after selecting an option the text color is still black.

This is my HTML

```
<form *ngIf="videos">
    <mat-form-field class="search-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Gamer-Tags" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption (optionSelected)='searchChange($event.option.value)'>
        <mat-option class="auto-option" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

This is my SCSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {color: white !important;}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline, ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple {background-color: white !important; color: white !important }
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-empty.mat-form-field-label { color: white !important;}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple { background-color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find out how to change it, needed to add this code to change the input's class color.

```
::ng-deep input.mat-input-element { color: white; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**for Angular 10**

component.sccs

```
.buscador {
    color: white !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: white !important; 
 }
 :host ::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline .mat-form-field-ripple {
 background-color: white !important;
```

}

component.html

```
  <form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label id="placeholder" class="buscador">Buscar...</mat-label>
        <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" type="text" name="option" required minlength="3">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" name="option">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options | async" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing mat input autofill `background color` you can simply use
In your main  `style.scss/css` you can use

```
.mat-form-field-autofill-control{
  background-color: wheat; // your prefered color 
}
```